# SQL and find records that don't match a criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone help me with the following statement.  I'm new to SQL and maybe overlooking the obvious.

I am trying to run the following query
There is a shipments table with the corresponding columns (PROJECTNO, SUPPLIERNO)
I know I don't the to put SHIPMENTS. in front of the names, but this will eventually end up in a multi table query.

```
SELECT sup1.SHIPMENTS.PROJECTNO, sup2.SHIPMENTS.PROJECTNO
FROM SHIPMENTS sup1, SHIPMENTS sup2
WHERE sup1.SHIPMENTS.PROJECTNO = sup2.SHIPMENTS.PROJECTNO
AND sup1.SHIPMENTS.SUPPLIERNO <> sup2.SHIPMENTS.SUPPLIERNO;
```

I keep getting the following error.

> ```
> ORA-00904: "SUP2"."SHIPMENTS"."SUPPLIERNO": invalid identifier
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
> *Cause:    
> *Action:
> Error at Line: 160 Column: 34
> ```

THanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the **{}** toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 1):

Change all **sup2.SHIPMENTS.SUPPLIERNO** to **sup2.SUPPLIERNO**, and do the same for sup1 alias, and for the other colummns.

You must understand aliasing. Once you alias table TAB as T then you should refer to it as simply T.

In your FROM clause, when you say

```
 FROM SHIPMENTS sup1, SHIPMENTS sup2
```

you are aliasing the SHIPMENTS table as sup1 and sup2 (as 2 instances of same table). So you need to use sup1 and sup2 as the table name, and the real name (SHIPMENTS) isn't valid, and would be ambiguous anyway, so use:

```
sup1.SUPPLIERNO --refers to SUPPLIERNO column in SHIPMENTS table aliased as sup1
sup2.PRODUCTNO  --refers to PRODUCTNO column in SHIPMENTS table aliased as sup2
```

there is no such thing as sup2.SHIPMENTS.SUPPLIERNO because there is no such thing as a sup2.SHIPMENTS table

Also, a general rule to keep in mind, in Oracle you can use notation like table.column, schema.table or schema.table.column to refer to tables/views or columns. In this case what you've written amounts to table.table.column which doesn't make sense (unless you were using a nested table).

The reason you must use aliasing here is that it is the only way to join a table to itself. If you use the full table name twice, you'll get ambiguity errors. When you self-join a table, Oracle treats each instance (alias) as a distinct table in the query. I prefer to use aliases like a and b to reduce typos.

```
 SELECT a.PROJECTNO, b.PROJECTNO
 FROM SHIPMENTS a JOIN SHIPMENTS b USING(PROJECTNO)
 WHERE a.SUPPLIERNO <> b.SUPPLIERNO;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be written as:

```
SELECT sup1.PROJECTNO, sup2.PROJECTNO
FROM SHIPMENTS sup1 JOIN
     SHIPMENTS sup2
     on sup1.PROJECTNO = sup2.SHIPMENTS.PROJECTNO AND
        sup1.SUPPLIERNO <> sup2.SUPPLIERNO;
```

First, when using an alias there is no need to specify the table name again.  Also, you should use explicit `join` syntax, with an `on` condition.  The implicit syntax, with the condition in the `where` clause, is supported, but it is less powerful and more difficult to read.